# Looping Through Variable and doing Permutation Means Difference Tests per Variable

Tags: r, loops, permutation

So I have a data set that is a much bigger version of this:

```
value <- c(4, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4)
category <- rep(c("good", "bad"), c(6, 6))
gene <- rep(c("gene_1", "gene_2"), 3)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(category, gene, value))

   category   gene value
1      good gene_1     4
2      good gene_2     6
3      good gene_1     7
4      good gene_2     2
5      good gene_1     3
6      good gene_2     4
7       bad gene_1     4
8       bad gene_2     6
9       bad gene_1     7
10      bad gene_2     2
11      bad gene_1     3
12      bad gene_2     4
```

I need to do a permutation test looking for the mean differences in the "value" between the "categories" *for each gene*.

My question is two fold:

1) How do I create an outer loop that will cycle through each gene and do the permutation test,

and

2) is this code for doing the permutation test otherwise correct?

```
y <- df$value
x <- df$category

obs <- mean(y[x == "good"]) - mean(y[x == "bad"])
## Permutation test
perm <- NULL
for(i in 1:1000){
  y.perm <- sample(y, replace=FALSE, size=100) 
  perm[i] <- mean(y.perm[x == "good"]) - mean(y.perm[x == "bad"])
}

## Two-sided p-value:
twosided <- sum(abs(perm) >= abs(obs))/1000
```

Here is an example of the tail of my data set:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   category, gene [2]
  category gene     value
  <fct>    <chr>    <dbl>
1 bad      gene_145  8.54
2 good     gene_145  8.40
3 good     gene_145  8.46
4 bad      gene_145  8.56
5 good     gene_145  8.25
6 bad      gene_145  8.43
```

So you can see it is basically identical to the sample df. Additionally here is the str of the nested actual data and the nested sample df:

```
> str(nest(df, -gene)) #sample df
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ gene: chr  "gene_1" "gene_2"
 $ data:List of 2
  ..$ :'data.frame':    6 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ category: Factor w/ 2 levels "bad","good": 2 2 2 1 1 1

> str(nest(merged_df, -gene)) #actual data
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   200 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ category: Factor w/ 2 levels "bad","good": 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ gene    : chr  "gene_1" "gene_1" "gene_3" "gene_3" ...
 $ data    :List of 200
  ..$ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    19 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ value: num  4.84 5.38 5.3 5.47 4.88 ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take the second question first. It is perhaps a better question for Cross Validated, but as it's closely related to your programming question, we'll tackle it here. When it comes to permuted sampling, there are two main things to keep in mind:

1. Each permutation should be of the same size as your observed sample. This ensures that permuted samples will have (or at least have the potential for) the same variance as the observed.
2. When possible, one should shuffle the *labels*, not the values (see this [Cross Validated question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204813/permutation-testing)). This fulfills the original intent of permutation sampling: creating alternatives where the *collected data* remained the same, but the data's *categories* ended up arbitrarily different. In situations such as yours, one should generally sample the labels without replacement, so that you end up with the same number of observations per group as you had originally (imbalances and all).

Suppose we have this example data (note that I made some small changes to fix errors in your original):

```
value <- round(runif(12) * 10)
category <- rep(c("good", "bad"), c(6, 6))
gene <- rep(c("gene_1", "gene_2"), 3)
df <- data.frame(category, gene, value)

   category   gene value
1      good gene_1     8
2      good gene_2     0
3      good gene_1     4
4      good gene_2     8
5      good gene_1     3
6      good gene_2     9
7       bad gene_1     0
8       bad gene_2     3
9       bad gene_1     7
10      bad gene_2     0
11      bad gene_1     5
12      bad gene_2     2
```

Permutation test code might look like:

```
perm <- rep(NA, 1000)
  for (i in 1:1000) {
    labels <- sample(df$category, nrow(df), replace=FALSE)
    perm[i] <- mean(df$value[labels == "good"]) - mean(df$value[labels == "bad"])
  }
```

To your other question, we can perform this operation per each gene in the data frame with the **tidyverse**. A full explanation of how these functions operate would be well beyond the scope of the question, but briefly, we use `nest` to "roll up" the data frame for each level of "gene", into a nested data frame generically called "data". We then use `mutate` and the `map` functions to operate on the nested frames, implementing the permutation code from above.

```
library(tidyverse)

df.nest <- nest(df, -gene) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    obs = map_dbl(data, function(x) mean(x$value[x$category == 'good']) - mean(x$value[x$category == 'bad']) ), 
    permutes = map(data, function(x) {
      perm <- rep(NA, 1000)
      for (i in 1:1000) {
        labels <- sample(x$category, nrow(x), replace=FALSE)
        perm[i] <- mean(x$value[labels == "good"]) - mean(x$value[labels == "bad"])
      }
      return(perm)
    }),
    p.val = map2_dbl(obs, permutes, function(obs, permutes) {
      mean(abs(permutes) >= abs(obs))
    })
  )

  gene   data                   obs permutes      p.val
  <fct>  <list>               <dbl> <list>        <dbl>
1 gene_1 <data.frame [6 × 2]>     1 <dbl [1,000]> 0.9  
2 gene_2 <data.frame [6 × 2]>     4 <dbl [1,000]> 0.388
```

Comment: Thansk so much for your answer. I am running these unfamiliar functions seperately on my df example here and my actual data to understand them better. The nest function on the df here seems to make sense. It takes the gene and nests all the relevant values associates with it. It removes the category, however. On my actual data it does not remove the category.  Why is that/will it be a problem?

Comment: This use of `nest` should create a data frame with a column for "gene", and a column called "data" containing the rest of the original data frame. So category isn't gone, but its redundant labeling has been separated from the original data.

Comment: Also, the map_dbl function I understand but I don't get the first argument to it. "data" doesn't exist elsewhere, right? And the first argument is .x a list/atomic vector. Is this "data" being created using this function, meaning is the object "obs" being created as an atomic vector?

Comment: Using the nest function on my data, the category remains and splits the gene_1 into two rows, one for good and one for bad. This didn't happen with the sample df, which is where my confusion is. And it sounds like that might cause trouble in the actual application? I did make sure that the str of the df and my actual data is the same, too.

Comment: I can’t diagnose problems in data sets I don’t have.

Comment: Of course. I put the tail of my data set in my question. As you can see it is identical to the sample df. All the classes for the various columns are the same.

Comment: Actually, the nest function just doesn't seem to be working. If I use -gene or -category or c(-gene, -category) or nothing at all, it gives me the same result.

Comment: Figured it out. The issue was simply that the data frame was not a tibble. If I do nest(as_tibble(df), -gene) it works. Thanks for your help!